# Problems with MySQL in Python

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, mysql-connector-python

I'm currently building a python flask web app. When I run it I get several ERRORS about lost connection to the MySQL server. Can someone help me, please?

`mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2013: Lost connection to MySQL server during query` 
`mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: MySQL Connection not available.`

`mysql.connector.errors.OperationalError: 2055: Lost connection to MySQL server at 'eu-cdbr-west-01.cleardb.com:3306', system error: 1 [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2570)`

I get those errors when I upload it to Heroku and also on my local computer. It's also weird that it's sometimes working and sometimes not.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a library? My previous experience with flask <-> sql has been through [pymysql](https://pypi.org/project/PyMySQL/).

here's the connection and return function i used the last time i set it up, this, may however be out of date since the new version of pymysql was added.

```
def connect_to_db():
    '''this function connects the database to the website'''
    return pymysql.connect(  host = db_host(),
                             user = db_username,
                             password = my_secrets.hunter2,
                             db = 'some_db',
                             charset = 'utf8mb4',
                             cursorclass = pymysql.cursors.DictCursor,
                             )
def return_db():
    '''Opens a new database connection per request.'''
    if not hasattr(g, 'db'):
        g.db = connect_to_db()
    return g.db
```

Notice here that the return function requires importing the [flask g object](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.0.x/api/#flask.g)

It also looks like SSL is one of the problems you're running into. SSL can be a big pain when changing versions especially on OSX.